How to View React.js pages in the browser
Sounds like a really stupid question, but I'm new to React and I learned to create react apps with the CDN Links and the "npx create-react-app" functions.
Now, I have the files that support the book I'm reading, and I want to view the chapters in a web browser. Most of the files are JavaScript files. Can anyone please tell me how I can do that without pulling my hair out?
I'm set-up as Windows/Apache/htdocs/etc..

Hi, I'm not sure if I understand the context enough. Do you want to know how to build a React View Page, display a book on a Page, or use a particular React package?

I'm reading a book and the book is accompanied with files for each chapter. I want to view the React.js files in my browser. I usually do it by creating a react app and then run npm start, or I include the CDN links to load the react.js library. Is there an easier way of viewing these React.js pages in the browser?

You could use StackBlitz. It's great platform to build things online. You can create React project without installation, and you can copy and paste the snippets of code your are trying to view from the book.

I'm using Visual Studio Code.

If you want to follow the examples locally I recommend you to use NextJs or Vite. Because create-react-app is deprecated.

I heard it was deprecated.

StackBlitz is super useful especially if you're trying things in React.

To run the server, you need to run these commands in the terminal.
npm install
npm start

